# No devices detected + Reset

Tags: usb, reset, hub

My Raspberry worked fine until last month, now it doesn't detect ANY device. I tested it with a wireless keyboard and it doesn't work. I tested it with a basic keyboard and a basic mouse and the doesn't work. All these devices worked fine since last month.
Also Raspbian continues to reset the raspberry on startup. NOOBS also continues to reset the Raspberry.

I think the internal USB hub is gone. Any chance to fix it?

Comment: Have you tried a fresh install of the operating system?  It might be a corrupted card.  You can backup your existing files/settings by plugging the sd card into a linux/mac box and copying the files off.

Comment: To do this on a Windows computer, turn it into an .img file using win32diskimager and extract the data using a file manager such as [7zip](http://www.7-zip.org/).

Comment: Check your power supply. It looks like any device, even the internal hub, doesn't have enough power.

Comment: Just tried with a mac power supply (output: 2A) and it is the same thing. I will try with a new raspbian installation but i don't think is a os problem (raspian continues to reset with raspbian & noobs)

Comment: Sometimes i got this error : nyet/nak/ack/other i non-error case
Tried with 3 different power supplies, no devices works .

Comment: SOLVED THE PROBLEM : The problem was the usb cable !!!

Comment: It looks your power supply does not provide enough power. Look at this thread. http://www.raspberrypi.org/phpBB3/viewtopic.php?p=143582

Comment: Have you solved this issue yet? If so, could you please create a self-answer and mark it as such. We are trying to get the Q:A ratio up and that would help us a ton. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

The problem was the USB cable.